# how to set the number of facet in solr by default

Tags: solr, numbers, facet

Does anybody know how I can set the number of default facets in solr? when I leave it to it, it give so large number of facets.
best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.limit): the parameter you're looking for is `facet.limit`, its default value is 100.